# Finding specific value in a cell array

Tags: matlab

Here is my cell array which is 2x2.

```
A = {'34TA894' 'Some string goes here.' ; '06AC532' 'Some string goes here too.'}
```

I am trying to find which row of the cell contains 34TA894. I tried to use find function as intended but it did not work. I've tried to convert my cell into a matrice to use it in the find function.But it gave me error "Matrice dimensions must agree."

Comment: The documentation for [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) contains one approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[row,col]=find(strcmp(A,'34TA894'));
```

[`strcmp(s1,s2)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) compares *s1* and *s2* and returns a boolean matrix indicating where they are identical.

`strcmpi(s1,s2)` is the same as strcmp except it is case insensitive.

[`strfind(str,pattern)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) compares *s1* and *pattern* and returns a cell array of indices indicating the locations of *pattern* within each element of *str*.